# copy selected file into documents folder swift3,osx

Tags: macos, cocoa, swift3

i would like to realize:
the user click on an button > finder window will open > the user select one ore more files > and this selected file/files should copy into the documents folder.

what I have at the moment:

```
@IBAction func copyFile(_ sender: Any) {
   let dialog = NSOpenPanel();
   dialog.showsHiddenFiles = false
   dialog.canChooseDirectories = false
   dialog.canCreateDirectories = false
   dialog.allowsMultipleSelection = true
   dialog.allowedFileTypes = ["pdf","doc","docx"]

   if (dialog.runModal() == NSModalResponseOK) {
       for x in 0..<dialog.urls.count {

          // documents folder path
          let dictDocuments = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0])

          // folder name
          let logsPath = dictDocuments.appendingPathComponent("Files/")

          print("SOURCE: ",dialog.urls[x].absoluteURL)
          print("TARGET: ",logsPath!)

          do {
              try FileManager.default.copyItem(at:    dialog.urls[x].absoluteURL, to: logsPath!)
          } catch let error as NSError {}
       }
    } else {
        return
    }
}
```

This is the output:

```
SOURCE:  file:///Users/XXX/Downloads/test.pdf
TARGET:  file:///Users/XXX/Documents/Files/
open on /Users/XXX/Documents/Files: File exists
```

The folder "Files" exists, but it is empty.
What did I wrong?

Comment: You forgot to append the file name to your target

Comment: you are right ! thank you very much